# Scope of Haloform reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

We know that methyl ketones and secondary alcohols oxidizable to methyl ketones, such as isopropanol. The only primary alcohol and aldehyde to undergo this reaction are ethanol and acetaldehyde, respectively. 1,3-Diketones such as acetylacetone also give the haloform reaction.
Do Terminal Alkynes give Haloform Reaction if Yes then how the mechanism will follow?

Comment: Maybe if you react with H2SO4/HgSO4 to make an aldehyde beforehand. I don't think a plain terminal alkyne will give the haloform test.

Comment: And if it is attached to some aromatic ring ?

Comment: You should read this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135626/do-cyclohexane-1-3-diones-give-positive-haloform-reactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terminal alkynes, including phenyl acetylene, react with iodine (in MeOH) to give 1,2-diiodoalkenes according to this JOC paper  [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1021/jo01311a020). Presence or absence of base will not alter the outcome. Presence of AgNO3 gives some di-iodo ketone which can then give rise to the iodoform reaction.